# None of the success and failure blocks are getting executing

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

This is my code

```
  let url = URL(string: "http://demo6680989.mockable.io/getData")
    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()

    manager.get((url?.absoluteString)!, parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: {
        (dataTask, responseObj) in

        if let dict : NSDictionary = responseObj as? NSDictionary {

            //print("Response: \(dict)")
            AuditListParser().parseAudit(jsonData: dict)
        }
    }, failure: {
        (dataTask, error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    })
```

When I used this url in browser it is giving me some data but when i execute the above code it is neither going into success block nor fialure block. 
1st time it was running properly and printed the data. I dont what happened suddenly, when i run it again this problem came

please help me

Comment: are you added the NSTransportSecurity in your .plist

Comment: yea @Anbu.Karthik, I have added

Comment: @RamcharanReddy Add print statement in your success block before the `if let`.

Comment: check  your URL is passed correctly or not

Comment: tried that. none of them getting printed. this is the problem here @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: print once this url?.absoluteString

Comment: the same url above is i'm using. even u can see the data inside this url. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if empty space is added then url is return nil

Comment: I've cross checked it. But there are spaces and also "http://demo6680989.mockable.io/getData" is the absolute string

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135020/discussion-between-ramcharan-reddy-and-anbu-karthik).

Comment: problem is resolved or not bro

Comment: No @Anbu.Karthik...

Comment: where u struck.

Comment: same problem... using breakpoints, control not going into any of closures

Comment: data is passed but you are nt get any response ,

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik 
i dont even whether the data has passed

Comment: ok try this sent the static data and static URL once

Comment: I don't get you karthik.. tell me how to send it.@Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @RamcharanReddy, check my answer below.

Comment: Breakpoints won't be called in asynchronous code. (Your success and failure block)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s `GET:(NSString *)URLString parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters success:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLSessionDataTask *task , id responseObject ))success failure:(void ( ^ ) ( NSURLSessionDataTask *task , NSError *error ))failure` method returns `NSURLSessionDataTask` object. So, you should start that task somehow for it to return in success or failure block. Just get the object that is being returned from `get()` method, and call `resume()` method of that object. Good luck!

**EDIT**

Like this:

```
let task = manager.get((url?.absoluteString)!, parameters: nil, progress: nil, success: {
        (dataTask, responseObj) in

        if let dict : NSDictionary = responseObj as? NSDictionary {

            //print("Response: \(dict)")
            AuditListParser().parseAudit(jsonData: dict)
        }
    }, failure: {
        (dataTask, error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    })
task.resume()
```

Comment: the same code is working in another machine.
the same code was running in this machine earlier.I dont know what happend. now it is not working @Fahri Azimov

Comment: yea @Fahri Azimov, I've tried your code also. the task object is in running state only